# High level overview of `auto.arima` with `xreg` predictors

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to understand how `auto.arima` with covariates in the xreg parameter works. I'm familiar with regression and I'm starting to work on forecasting.

My understanding of forecasting is that you look for patterns in the past time series and then project those paterns onto the future.

My uderstanding of regression is that you use predictors to try to generate an output value and minimize the difference between your created value and the real value.

So how does forecasting `auto.arima` with `xreg` work? Do you create a forecast for a timeseries based on past data and regression model based on the input time series and input `xreg`, and then forecast each data point in the time series and for each forecasted data point use the regression model you built and future `xreg` values to adjust the forecasted values?

I'm a former physics grad student, so I'm not allergic to math but I'm just looking for a high level overview of the process here to understand how forecasting `auto.arima` works.

For example like,

- step 1: build forecast model on input time series, and regression model on input time series and input `xreg` values
- step 2: forecast model into future one step, and predict value with regression model and future `xreg` values
- step 3: algorithm combines forecasted value and regression model prediction to get combined value

This is just a guess at how it works, but it's an example of the kind of high level explanation I'm looking for.

I've included some code below that I've been working on trying to forecast time in to out `TiTo` for customers at a restaurant with predictor count of customers in the restaurant `CustCount`.

```
OV<-zoo(SampleData$TiTo, 
    order.by=SampleData$DateTime)


eDate <- ts(OV, frequency = 24)

Train <-eDate[1:15000]
Test <- eDate[15001:22773]

xregTrain <- SampleData[1:15000,]$CustCount
    xregTest <- SampleData[15001:22773,]$CustCount

Arima.fit <- auto.arima(Train, xreg = xregTrain)

Acast<-forecast(Arima.fit, h=7772, xreg = xregTest)

accuracy(Acast$mean,Test)
```

Comment: Software-specific questions tend to be frowned upon here, so you may want to re-frame this as how an ARIMA model could be automatically built, rather than how `auto.arima` works. (The latter is arguably off topic, & you could just look at the code anyway.)

Comment: I think the real question is not about `auto.arima` but rather about regression with ARMA errors as implemented in `arima` with exogenous regressors. Try Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) and Hyndman & Khandakar ["Automatic time series forecasting: the forecast package for R"](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/automatic-forecasting/) (2008).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the real question is not about `auto.arima` but rather about regression with ARMA errors as implemented in `arima` with exogenous regressors.

> So how does forecasting `auto.arima` with `xreg` work? Do you create a forecast for a time series based on past data and regression model based on the input time series and input `xreg`, and then forecast each data point in the time series and for each forecasted data point use the regression model you built and future `xreg` values to adjust the forecasted values?

No, this is not how it works. It is simpler than that. Let us call the time series of interest $y$ and the exogenous regressors $X$. In a regression with ARMA errors as implemented in `arima` (and `auto.arima`) with `xreg`, the model equations are

$$
\begin{align}
y_t &= \beta' X_t + u_t \\
u_t &= \varphi_1 u_{t-1} + \dotsc + \varphi_p u_{t-p} + \varepsilon_t + \theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1} + \dotsc + \theta_q\varepsilon_{t-q}
\end{align}
$$

where $u_t$ is not $i.i.d.$ but $\varepsilon_t$ is.

The "main" equation is the upper one which specifies a linear relationship between $y_t$ and $X_t$ and looks very much like a regular regression model. The difference from a regular regression is made by the second equation that specifies the error term $u_t$ to follow an ARMA($p,q$) process (instead of $u_t$ being uncorrelated as would be the case in a regular regression). The second equation serves to "fix the problem with the first equation's errors". I like to think of this model as basically the good old regression but with unpleasant error pattern that needs to be accounted for.

How does `auto.arima` differ from `arima` in this case? `auto.arima` selects the optimal autoregressive and moving-average orders $p$ and $q$ based on a chosen information criterion (AICc by default, alternatively AIC or BIC) from a local search over a few regions of values. Meanwhile, `arima` requires the user to specify $p$ and $q$ manually.

How are these models fit? Generally, by maximum likelihood estimation. Refering to your three-step example algorithm, `arima` can be done in one step where all the parameters ($\beta$s, $\varphi$s and $\theta$s) are estimated at once together producing the fitted values $\hat y_t$ and the residuals $\hat\varepsilon_t$. `auto.arima` would do that multiple times as it tries out different values of $p$ and $q$.

See more in the Hyndman & Khandakar ["Automatic time series forecasting: the forecast package for R"](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/automatic-forecasting/) (2008). Also, try Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

Comment: Richard, thank you very much for your response.  This is very helpful.  I read the Hyndman blog post and the paper from the forecast package that you suggested.  I've been reading a lot of Rob Hyndman's posts, they're very helpful.  So if I'm understanding this correctly the Ut equation is the part that accounts for any sort timeseries/seasonality type pattern to Y?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: If I compare the coefficients of a `(ts)lm` and the corresponding `auto.arima` +`xreg`, how do the relate? At first I thought, they should be the same, because the ARIMA is just fit on the errors, but the coefficients seem to change quite a bit. Is this because of the "timeseries"-pattern is already accounted simultaneously for during the fitting process? Could you give a little more detail? (also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184004/r-auto-arima-with-xreg-vs-lm) @RichardHardy

Comment: @stats-hb, yes, it is because the model is fit in one stage, not stepwise, and the ARIMA-errors are affecting the estimates of the linear model equation.