# Unconditional mean and variance of a stationary VAR(1) model

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, vector-autoregression

I am confused while trying to find a general expression for the mean and variance of a stationary VAR model.  I am trying to do it for VAR(1).  I also can't find it in the literature.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 11):

Taking the variance of both sides of the equation
$$
y_t = \nu + A_1 y_{t-1} + u_t
$$
leads to
$$
\operatorname{Var}y_t = A_1\operatorname{Var}y_{t-1}A_1^T+\Sigma_u.
$$
Stationary implies that $\operatorname{Var}y_t =\operatorname{Var}y_{t-1}=\Gamma_0$ so you need to solve the matrix equation
$$
\Gamma_0 = A_1\Gamma_0 A_1^T+\Sigma_u.
$$
Applying the vec-function, this can be rewritten [(see wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) as
$$
\operatorname{vec}\Gamma_0 = (A_1\otimes A_1) \operatorname{vec}\Gamma_0 + \operatorname{vec}\Sigma_u
$$
and solved using standard methods for the unknown covariances given by
$$
\operatorname{vec}\Gamma_0 = (I-A_1\otimes A_1)^{-1} \operatorname{vec}\Sigma_u.
$$
So you don't need to work out the infinite sum from the MA$(\infty)$-representation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the result is the same but your representation is more convenient as it readily yields an empirically feasible solution (unlike the infinite sum).

Comment: Yes, it's just two different ways of expressing the same covariance matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quite what I was looking for. Not sure why the answer is not accepted. It should be.

Answer (score 6):

According to Lütkepohl (2005), p. 14-15, if we have a $K$-variate VAR(1) process of the form
$$
y_t = \nu + A_1 y_{t-1} + u_t,
$$
then the **unconditional mean** is 
$$
(I_K-A_1)^{-1}\nu
$$
(where $I_K$ is an identity matrix of dimension $K\times K$) and the **unconditional covariance** for lag $h$ (i.e. $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-h})$) is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty A_1^{h+i}\Sigma_u {A_1^i}'
$$
where $\Sigma_u$ is the covariance matrix of the error term $u_t$. Then the **unconditional variance** can be obtained by taking $h=0$ in the above expression.

The same applies to VAR($p$) after having expressed the process in its alternative $Kp$-dimensional VAR(1) representation.

These results are obtained using the vector moving-average (VMA) representation of the VAR(1) process.

**References**

- Lütkepohl, Helmut. *New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis.* Springer Science & Business Media, 2005.

Comment: Is there a way to derive the unconditional variance?

Comment: @Bonsaibubble, the answer by Jarle Tufto does that.

Comment: But how does this correspond to what Lütkepohl defines?

Comment: @Bonsaibubble, both answers agree on the substance (they do not imply different things), they just use different approach and notation.

Comment: Ok, I dont understand Tufto's approach then

Comment: Is a proof of Lütkepohl approach available somewhere?

Comment: @Bonsaibubble, p. 15 in Lütkepohl's textbook has it.

Comment: It defines the mean vector but a proof is not given

Comment: It is not given in detail, but there are pointers to Appendices etc. that should make up for that. But if you cannot follow it, then of course another source would be more helpful.

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't own the book you are referring to. Could you define $h$? Why does $h=0$  correspond to the unconditional variance. What does it correspond to when $h \neq 0$? Many thanks

Comment: @Hunter, I have updated my answer. $h$ is the time lag of autocovariance of $y_t$. A lag of $h=0$ corresponds to covariance of $y_t$ with itself (i.e. variance), while a lag of $h \neq 0$ corresponds to covariance between $y_t$ and $y_{t-h}$.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks, makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @RichardHardy Hi Richard, I am a big fan of your answers, including this old [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198844/high-level-overview-of-auto-arima-with-xreg-predictors) that you have about Arimax and regressions with time-series errors. I am dealing with a regression with Garch Error term and searching for good sources because I have some doubts on the way I have to write the likelihood function.. Arimax models are ok as an alternative to a regression with Garch errors.. do you know any?

Comment: @RichardHardy as you may see from my yesterday question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420946/writing-the-likelihood-and-conditional-variance-in-a-armax-model-or-regression-w) I got a bit confused yesterday on the way I have to write the conditional variance of the Error term in the likelihood

Comment: @RichardHardy ok many thanks in advance!