# Calculate $E [ Z_{t-1}| X_{t-1}]$ in an ARMA process

Tags: time-series, arima, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have an ARMA(1,1) model:
$$X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + Z_t + \theta Z_{t-1}, \quad Z_t \sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$$

Indeed, I want calculate $E[X_t | X_{t-1}]$. For this:

\begin{align}
E[X_t | X_{t-1}] &= \phi X_{t-1} + E[Z_t | X_{t-1}]  + \theta E [ Z_{t-1}| X_{t-1}]\\
&= \phi X_{t-1} + \theta E [ Z_{t-1}| X_{t-1}]
\end{align}
I used the fact that for $j>0$, $X_t$ and $Z_{t+j}$ are independent. Thus, they are mean independent: $E[Z_t|X_{t-1}]= E[Z_t]=0$. But I don't know how to calculate $E [ Z_{t-1}| X_{t-1}]$.

I don't know if this the best way to calculate $E[X_t | X_{t-1}]$. If there is another way to calculate, I would also like to know!

Answer (score 4):

For the Gaussian ARMA model we can derive the conditional mean and variance using standard results for conditional moments for the multivariate normal distribution.  This requires use of the auto-correlation function for the ARMA model.  You can find details of how to compute the autocorrelation function for an ARMA model in Section 3.3 of [Brockwell and Davis (1991)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-0320-4).  Details of how to compute the conditional distribution and moments can be found in [O'Neill (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12416), which describes the functions in the [`ts.extend` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ts.extend).  First we derive the autocorrelation function $\gamma$ at the relevant lag values (zero and one in this case):

$$\gamma(k) \equiv \mathbb{Corr}(X_t,X_{t-k}).$$

Using these values we can then write the conditional expectation of interest as:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t | X_{t-1} = x)
= \mu + \gamma(1) (x - \mu).$$

(In this equation I have included a mean term $\mu$ for the Gaussian ARMA model, even though this mean is zero in your question.)  The conditional expectation of interest to you can be computed using the functions in the `ts.extend` package.  Here is an example using the parameters $\mu = 0$, $\phi = 0.8$ and $\theta = -0.3$.

```
#Set model parameters
mu    <- 0
phi   <- 0.8
theta <- -0.3

#Compute autocorrelation
AUTOCORR  <- ts.extend::ARMA.autocov(n = 2, ar = phi, ma = theta, corr = TRUE)
CORR.LAG1 <- AUTOCORR[2]

#Compute and plot conditional expectation
x <- (-30:30)/10
E <- mu + CORR.LAG1*(x - mu)
plot(x, E, type = 'l', xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3),
     main = 'Conditional Expectation in Gaussian ARMA Model',
     xlab = 'X[t-1]', ylab = 'E(X[t] | X[t-1])')
```

[image]

Comment: So, Can I say $\mathbb{E}(X_t | X_{t-1} ) = \mu + \gamma(1) (X_{t-1} - \mu)$? How do I get to $\mathbb{E}(X_t | X_{t-1} )$ from $\gamma(k)$  ? But with $\mu =0$, we have $\mathbb{E}(X_t | X_{t-1} ) =  \gamma(1) (X_{t-1} )$. In others words, are you saying that $E(X_t|X_{t-1})= cov(X_,X_{t-1}) X_{t-1}$?

Comment: $*E(X_t|X_{t-1})= cov(X_t,X_{t-1}) X_{t-1}$?

Comment: I am trying to use $cov(X,Y)=cov(X, E[Y|X] )$. In my case,  $\gamma(1 ):= cov(X_{t-1},X_t)=cov(X_{t-1}, E[X_t|X_{t-1}] ) = E( X_{t-1} E( X_t | X_{t-1} )  )$ since $E(x_t )=0$ in the last equality. So,  $\gamma(1 )= E( X_{t-1} E( X_t | X_{t-1} )  )$